# How can I upgrade the Ubuntu LTS kernel to newer?

Tags: kernel, lts, hardware-enablement-stack

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04.2 64-bit on my desktop PC and I see the kernel in System Monitor is 3.5.0-23 but in Ubuntu 12.04.2 in my laptop the kernel is 3.2.0-38.

I have already tried to run the command `sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` on my laptop but it doesn't update the kernel.

How can I upgrade kernel for my laptop?

Comment: Just in case someone does not know: Ubuntu 12.04 has Kernel 3.2 while Ubuntu 12.10 has Kernel 3.5. For more information, visit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Table_of_versions

Answer (score 36, accepted):

New deployments of 12.04.2 will be installed with an updated kernel and a new X windows stack.
For existing 12.04 deployments, users will need to opt-in to what is being called the [LTS Hardware Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop#LTS_Hardware_Enablement_Stack). If you already have Ubuntu 12.04 installed with an earlier kernel stack, it is recommended that you keep this stack in place rather than switching to a later kernel; the newer kernel and X stacks are provided for enablement of hardware not supported by earlier kernels, and there is generally no reason to upgrade to a newer stack if your hardware is supported by the default kernel.

In order to upgrade to the 3.5 kernel on 12.04.2, you will need to run the following command(s):

For the new kernel:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-quantal
```

For the new X stack:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-lts-quantal
```

**WARNING: If you are using the xorg-edgers PPA, do not install the xserver-xorg-lts-quantal package as this will most likely result in breakage.**

Reference: https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa

This is only recommended for x86 hardware installations.

See also:

- The 12.04.2 [Release Notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes) for more details.
- [Quantal backported kernel in 12.04.2? What's going on there?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279391/quantal-backported-kernel-in-12-04-2-whats-going-on-there/279392#279392)
- [How to remove Kernel/LTS Enablement Stack?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/265999/how-to-remove-kernel-lts-enablement-stack)

Answer (score 7):

The simplest set of instructions I always used for kernel upgrade / downgrade are by ubuntuforums.org user by the name of lykwydchykyn (url modified by me for this post):

Go here: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/
Download 3 (maybe 4) debs to a folder somewhere:

```
linux-headers-VERSION-NUMBER_all.deb
linux-headers-VERSION-NUMBER_amd64.deb
linux-image-VERSION-NUMBER_amd64.deb
linux-image-extra-VERSION-NUMBER_amd64.deb   # if available
```

Install the debs with whatever package manager front-end you use (is gdebi still around?), or use these commands:

```
cd /path/to/folder/where/you/put/the/debs
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11391743#post11391743 and https://askubuntu.com/a/142000/133170

Comment: Forgot to add http://askubuntu.com/a/142000/133170 in the 'source'?

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can install 3.5.0 kernels, run `apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-quantal` to install the latest quantal 3.5.0 kernel. This package will ensure that you always have the latest quantal kernel.

I personally recommend raring's 3.8 (base on upstream 3.8.8) kernel anyway.

NOTE: search for available 3.5.0 kernels `apt-cache search linux-image-3.5.0`.

BTW: You can even manually download latest mainline kernels and install them, for example 3.7.9. However, if you install PPA mainline kernels manually, you'll have to manually install updates.

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

Comment: will I get kernel updates and fixes for kernels installed this way?

Comment: If you are talking about the kernel PPA mainline kernels, **NO**. If you install `linux-image-generic-lts-quantal`, it'll help you take care of the 3.5.0 security updates. I've updated the reply.

Answer (score 1):

Since 14.04.3, there are more packages you need to install on a desktop to get all the dependencies sorted:

This installs the new kernel, as before, and is sufficient on a CLI-only server:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

But with the X server you need a bunch of packages that these two pull through recommends:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends xserver-xorg-lts-vivid libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-vivid
```

Answer (score 0):

For the newest kernel available for 12.04:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-saucy
```

For the newest X stack available for 12.04:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-lts-raring
```