# How to remove Kernel/LTS Enablement Stack?

Tags: 12.04, kernel, virtualbox, lts, xserver

this question regarding the [LTS Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) has actually two parts:

1. I installed Linux 3.5.0-x on Precise 64bit via `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-quantal xserver-xorg-lts-quantal` . As it turns out, VirtualBox does [not work yet on the new kernel](http://launchpad.net/bugs/1081307) (EDIT: This is fixed now.). Therefore I want to remove it from the system. As expected removing the meta-packages via `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-quantal xserver-xorg-lts-quantal` is not enough. What packages do I need to remove manually? For the kernel I would do (as of now): `sudo apt-get remove linux-image-3.5.0-25-generic` . However, regarding xserver-org I am lost. How can I switch back to the original xserver?
2. I installed a system with the 12.04.2 installation media. There I have also the 3.5.0-x kernel, because that's the [default for this point release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop#PrecisePangolin.2BAC8-ReleaseNotes.2BAC8-CommonInfrastructure.Ubuntu_Kernel_3.5.0-23.35). How can I downgrade to the kernel (and xserver?) to the 3.2.0-x series?

Thank you!

Comment: Another way could be to use VirtualBox from this PPA until it gets fixed for Precise + kernel 3.5: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1081307/comments/4 . But still I am interested how to go from 3.5 to 3.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Important: The below instructions only work if you have one of the pre-enablement stack kernels installed still, e.g. 3.2.0-38.

With the Enablement Stack installed run 'uname -r' to check the current kernel version. Substitute it into the command below:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-generic-lts-quantal xserver-xorg-lts-quantal linux-headers-generic-lts-quantal linux-image-generic-lts-quantal linux-image-3.5.0-25-generic linux-headers-3.5.0-25
```

Re-install important components (including X itself!) that are removed due to dependencies by the above commands:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Fix the steam client:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```

Finally, reboot your computer.

IMHO the enablement stack isn't ready for release. In my experience Virtualbox, Samba, and the Steam client all break with the Enablement Stack installed. There's a workaround for Virtualbox but none for Samba or Steam so far (March 2013).

Answer (score 2):

In Trusty/14.04 there are a few more packages that need to be removed, or apt-get will complain.

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic
```

Then install `xserver-xorg` if not installed, reboot to old kernel version, remove 3.16 kernel(s) and you are good to go.

If you use Steam, you need to install two packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```

Answer (score 0):

A procedure for your consideration:

1. Uninstall the following packages:

   ```
   linux-generic-lts-quantal
   xserver-xorg-lts-quantal
   ```
2. Install the following packages:

   ```
   linux-generic
   linux-headers-generic
   linux-image
   linux-image-generic
   linux-libc-dev
   linux-tools
   ```
3. Reboot to 3.2.0-38 kernel
4. Uninstall the packages `linux-headers-3.5.0-x` and `linux-image-3.5.0-x`.

Good luck and have fun.

Comment: Thanks! What should I do about the graphics stack? Installing xserver-xorg-lts-quantal removes the "old" xserver-... Will it be re-installed automatically?

Comment: Original is restored.