# Screen tearing Intel Graphics 5500

Tags: 15.04, intel-graphics

What can I do to eliminate screen tearing and generally improve graphics performance? I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 on [kernel 4.0](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.0-vivid/). My machine is the HP Spectre x360 13-4009na.

Intel® Core™ i5-5200U
8 GB DDR3 Memory
256GB SSD storage
Intel HD Graphics 5500

**This is not a memory issue.**

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/596982/167115

Comment: Please see edit @mchid

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like intel configuration problem, and I suppose this is a duplicate of: [Screen tearing in Ubuntu with Nvidia/Intel graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/667466/screen-tearing-in-ubuntu-with-nvidia-intel-graphics/668590#668590)