# Graphic glitches, icons and text disappears with Thinkpad T450 and Ubuntu 14.10 Gnome

Tags: graphics, thinkpad

I bought Lenovo ThinkPad T450 with hope that it would work straight out of the box, most ThinkPads have really great support early on imo. But this laptop isn't really coping with me.

The problem I have is when I switch workspaces or something, the icons and text disapears and I can't see any, I have to hover my mouse over the different objects to see them. Switching workspaces back and forth works. I use I3 window manager but the problem is the same with Gnome 3.

Lets get down with some specs:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev e3)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller (rev 03)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 59)
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out it was this problem.

[14.04 Thinkpad T450: Text getting messed up on large screens](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594451/14-04-thinkpad-t450-text-getting-messed-up-on-large-screens)

Just did what the answer said and tada.

Comment: Mark your answer correct then, if you're allowed to.