# Firefox fonts unreadable, especially for Google sites

Tags: firefox, fonts

for some sites, Firefox renders the fonts unreadable. I've noticed this especially for the Google sites. When I uncheck the Firefox option "Allow pages to choose their own fonts, instead of my selections above", everything is readable again, but "beautiful" is it not.

I'm attaching two pictures, one with the Youtube menu and one with the pulldown menu of Google Maps.

[image]

[image]

Is there any way to go around this problem and show the original fonts of the website (so not by overwritting them) being shown correctly?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  ;-) This is a video module problem...  What video hardware are you using and which module version?

Comment: I'm using the internal Intel Video Adapter in an Thinkpad T450s:
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5036
...
        Kernel driver in use: i915

The module is i915 provided by 3.16.0-38-generic

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to my problem, documented here:
[14.04 Thinkpad T450: Text getting messed up on large screens](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594451/14-04-thinkpad-t450-text-getting-messed-up-on-large-screens)

Specifically:

Put the following:

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "AccelMethod"  "uxa"
EndSection
```

in file /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf, create the directory /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/ if it does not exist. This must be done as root:

```
$ sudo mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/
$ sudo cp  20-intel.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

Assuming you created the file 20-intel.conf in the local directory.

BTW, here's the source for the solution: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_graphics#SNA_issues

The problem with disabling SNA is that some graphic-intensive applications like a video Google Hangout are extremely slow.

The other workaround is documented in post #100 on https://bugs.launchpad.net/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1432194 - it worked allright on my 14.04.

Comment: Good one!  Upvoted!  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

ican't see your screenshots, but i had same issue, it was the solution:

this sounds like an issue with hardware acceleration - please try **updating your graphics driver**, **OR** in case this doesn't solve the issue or there is no new version available at the moment, **disable hardware acceleration** in `firefox > options > advanced > general.`