# Firefox fonts too small on Dell Inspiron

Tags: firefox, fonts, display-resolution

I use Firefox on Ubuntu 16.04, but the browser displays the webpages way too small. I have already tried to increase the font size, from the `preferences:contents` Firefox panel, but the result is super-ugly. For example, if I google something, the linkable text is as small as before while the description text is of the font size I have selected in the `preferences:contents` panel.

Then I tried to install new fonts, since this seems to be a possible solution for other users. I followed [this discussion to install `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543673/mscorefonts-problems). However, still nothing has changed.

The `Ctrl`+`+` button combination is not an actual solution: it has to be done at each page, and every time I open Firefox again.

Finally I tried the `View`+`Zoom` in the Firefox top bar, which seems to improve the situation a bit. But after zooming, when I open other webpages, some of them are displayed not very well and others still have very small font size (which may require to Zoom again and again):

[image]

Even for pages that are left zoomed, the result is not pleasant at all, therefore I believe there must be another solution that fix things without my manual tuning.

I don't know if [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/626053/firefox-fonts-unreadable-especially-for-google-sites) applies to my laptop as well, so any suggestion on this would be great. Ayway, it might be a start. (Even if there is a solution in that thread, the answer is not accepted)

[Hardware specs here](http://pastebin.com/n0BqiiLb).

Monitor resolution:

```
:~$ xdpyinfo  | grep dimensions
dimensions:    1920x1080 pixels (508x285 millimeters)
```

Could it be a problem of monitor resolution/dpi? What are the possible solutions?

Comment: From your screenshot I can tell you that the font sizes on that page is normal.

Comment: @Anwar, although it may seems so (even if not to me or to those who look at my laptop in person), I guarantee it is not. In the end, there should be a way to check it out, right?

Comment: I checked and even discussed with two other fellow AU member. They said there is no problem in the page. Btw, Ubuntu wiki pages have smaller font size. Try to use the page

Comment: @Anwar, I am sorry to insist, but I am sure of the problem. Wikipedia pages have also unbelievably small fonts. Even this forum is not displayed properly. Are you by any chance aware of a terminal that can quantify the situation?

Comment: What is your monitor resolution? Put a screenshot from Wikipedia. Also check Firefox font settings from preference

Comment: @Anwar, thanks. I updated my original question. Firefox settings were already discussed there.

Comment: I'd say the size is still very good and reasonable. Please zoom your browser settings if you have a problem. Also consider any health issues with your eyes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be installing Firefox add-on, I was using [Default FullZoom Level](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-US/firefox/addon/default-fullzoom-level/?src=userprofile) for this, its small and simple.

[image]

Comment: This seems to work! I'll wait to use the browser a bit more before accepting the answer, to check if there is any bug. Thanks!

Comment: It makes the (scaled up) image blurred, right?

Answer (score 1):

If your using firefox you can right click in the gray area of search bar, and then click on customize, it will take you to Additional Tools and Features, once there you can drag and drop your zoom-in and zoom-out controls into your search bar. Go here for more information https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customize-firefox-controls-buttons-and-toolbars?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=How+to+customize+the+toolbar

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` setting of your Firefox Config to increase the relative pixel size, per pixel. This is the solution I use on a high DPI, 4k screen running Ubuntu 18.04 and it works very well.

1. Click into your address bar (probably on a different tab than this one)
2. Type `about:config` and press enter (navigate to `about:config`)
3. In the search bar (if present), type `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` until the setting `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` appears below the search bar. Alternatively, scroll down through the list until you see that property.
4. Click the number in the "value column." A dialog box, or some other means of editing that number, should appear. Probably in that field right now is "-1.0."
5. Edit that number to be `2.0` and click "Ok."
6. Observe the results in a page with text that was previously too small. At this point, the text was too large to me, so I set the value to `1.5`. Make sure your zoom is set to the default zoom, probably 100%.

Comment: I set it to 1.2, the text is perfect, not too small not too large, but the image is blur. If I set to 2.0, the image is not blur, but it's too large.