# linux-source-3.5.0 for ubuntu 12.04.2?

Tags: kernel, source

I have Ubuntu 12.04.2 with kernel 3.5.0 and need to recompile some modules, but i`m getting hard to find the correct sources. apt-get only has sources for 3.2.0? Where i can get the correct sources for the installed kernel 3.5.0??

Comment: Maybe check if you have deb-src lines in /etc/apt/source.list for -updates and -security too?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/257617/how-can-i-upgrade-the-ubuntu-12-04-2-kernel-to-3-5-0-23

Nicer way :)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a major breakage to me. There are meta-packages that don't work at all, some link to the old 3.2.0 kernel.
For example, doing `apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)` will fail, as it tries to use `linux-lts-quantal` instead, and then fails as that package cannot be found. We've been trying around for two hours, before resorting to using their kernel git repository (which involved changing our scriptomatic relying on `apt-get source`, which we tried to prevent).

It's beyond me how you can "update" a release you call LTS in such a messed up way.

The solution for us right now is to use their kernel git repository, although it is huge and takes ages to clone.

```
git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-precise.git
cd ubuntu-precise
git tag -l Ubuntu-*     # show all tagged versions
git checkout -b temp Ubuntu-lts-3.5.0-28.48     # pick the one matching "uname -r"
```