# My Ubuntu system will not boot from GRUB until I select it from the boot menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-8

Okay, I went through the installation process to have dual OS; windows 8 and Ubuntu 14.04. No matter what I do my computer WILL NOT boot from the grub menu. To clarify I have already:

1. disabled secure boot and fast start
2. run boot repair from Ubuntu side
3. manually set `bootmgr` using Windows `bcdedit`:

   ```
   bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
   ```

If I do nothing and allow my computer to boot on its own I am directed to Windows.

If I go into the BIOS to reorder my boot options, my options do not include GRUB or Ubuntu

In order to access the Ubuntu partition I have to hit <kbd>esc</kbd> as my computer is booting and go into boot option menu where I have 6 different "ubuntu" options (none of which appear in my BIOs settings, as mentioned), all exactly the same in appearance except the working option is the only one that begins with a lower case "u". the rest indefinitely load a black screen.

After choosing the working Ubuntu option I am finally presented with the GRUB menu and my options are

```
Ubuntu            # takes me to OS
Advanced options for Ubuntu
Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi 
Windows boot UEFI loader
```

then 10 options that begin with `EFI/...`

```
Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda2)   # takes me to Windows 
System Setup.
```

I don't get why I have so many options here.

I have tried to use gparted to mess with partitions as I see other answers giving several solutions that way. However I have read [here in the Ubuntu help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition) that a new boot partition for a computer with Windows first need to be implemented via the Windows side to get it within the first 100 GB.

I am really just scared to continue making changes. I know my way somewhat around a computer, but I feel like there's a lot wrong here. I just want to boot from GRUB, have 2 options: Windows or Ubuntu. What now?

Comment: Perhaps you could try Wubi?

Comment: I think setting windows bootmgr to ubuntu was wrong. Why you did that?

Comment: @user2816870 ive read wubi doesnt word with windows 8, only 7 and vista.

Comment: @Pilot6 i saw multiple forums on this site, multiple people experiencing the same exact problems as me, and several of them using bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi to fix the problem, which it did. so i gave it a shot. In any case, it wasn't booting to grub before i did this, and it didnt fix it after.

Comment: Did you try booting from Super Grub Disk?

Comment: i don't know where that would be.. I don't believe that exists for me within the boot options.

Comment: The suggestion from Boot-Repair for boot files within the first 100GB of drive is for older BIOS systems or perhaps USB boot with BIOS. Have yet to set where a system with UEFI needs any changes unless your drive is over 2TB and boot files are beyond that point.  What brand/model computer?

Comment: definitely not 2 TB. its an HP envy though

Answer (score 1):

First, a separate `/boot` partition (as described on the [page to which you linked](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)) will do no good. In fact, setting one up could complicate matters in a way that will make it harder to find a solution. Thus, you should not pursue this option.

Second, you say you disabled "fast start," but it's not 100% clear from your description if you're referring to a firmware option or to the Windows option called "Fast Startup" (or sometimes "Hybrid Boot"). If the former, you should disable Fast Startup *in Windows,* as described [here](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html) (among many other places). Fast Startup basically turns a shutdown operation into a suspend-to-disk operation. One consequence of this change is that filesystems, including the [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) on which boot loaders are stored, are left in an unsafe state. It's possible, although not all *that* likely, that your problems are a consequence of this fact. Thus, you should disable Fast Startup and try your fixes again -- or at least the `bcdedit` fix you've noted.

If that doesn't help, it sounds as if your firmware is buggy. Unfortunately, some EFIs ignore their boot settings. A firmware update (probably called a "BIOS update" on the manufacturer's page) may fix the problem, although you'll still need to use `bcdedit` in Windows, `efibootmgr` in Linux, or some other tool, to create an appropriate boot entry.

If neither disabling Fast Startup nor updating the firmware fixes the problem and if the computer is new enough, I recommend you return it to the store for a refund and buy something else, then write to the manufacturer and tell them why you returned the computer. Unless and until people start returning their defective computers, manufacturers won't even know the problem exists, much less be motivated to fix it.

If the computer is not new enough to return, you'll need to engage in some type of workaround. The simplest of these is probably to rename your boot loader files so that GRUB gets the name that's normally used by the Windows boot loader (`EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` on the ESP). The Boot Repair tool has an option to do this (and move the Microsoft boot loader and update GRUB appropriately) on its Advanced options menu. It's called something like "Back up and rename boot files," but I don't recall the precise phrase used.

As to your excessive number of menu options in GRUB, I'm not certain of the cause, except in general terms: The scripts that create those boot entries can become confused and generate too many entries. Some people say that the [GRUB Customizer](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer) tool can help tame the menu in such situations, but I've never used it myself. (I'm not a GRUB fan, and prefer to use almost anything else instead, -- but switching to another boot loader most likely won't solve your primary problem, since it must be registered with the EFI just like GRUB.)

Comment: Well I'm glad I stopped then and did not continue with the boot partition. As for the fast start, this was described to me through multiple help forums. I found this setting, and disabled it, through the power settings on the control panel. The computer is over a year old, and I believe that was the end of the manufacturers warranty, and the return date has passed as well for the purchaser.  Also, can you recommend an alternative to GRUB then, because as of now I have no idea how to continue on with it.

Comment: For alternatives to GRUB, see [this question and answers.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/313627/uefi-bootloader-alternative-to-grub) My own [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) is likely to be the easiest to set up and use. Note, however, that none of these is likely to help you get past the fundamental problem of a broken EFI. *Maybe* permanently using a rEFInd USB flash drive would help....

Comment: interesting. Well thanks for your help. I am half tempted to just leave windows all together.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: My Windows updated (I do not know what the update was) and after that my computer now boots to the GRUB menu. I made no other changes to my computer so I am assuming somehow the update could have possibly addressed the problem?

My only remaining issue is the fact that I'm still getting 10+ options on the GRUB menu. Ubuntu and the windows option I mention both work for booting to either OS, even though I would like the menu cleaned up I am satisfied for now that at least it is all working correctly. If anyone knows how to clean up the grub menu I am eager to know. I haven't researched this problem yet so I won't be creating a new question until I have looked into it. Thank you for everyone's input.