# Ubuntu UEFI Dual-Boot without boot repair

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have an HP Pavilion with Windows 8.1 pre-installed. I managed to dual boot Ubuntu 15.04 successfully. Then, I replaced the Windows Boot Loader with the grub loader as default by entering this command in the Windows command prompt:

bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi

However, I decided to uninstall Ubuntu and unwisely began by deleting the Ubuntu partition from the Windows Disk Manager. Predictably, this led to a corruption in my EFI partition, I could not boot into Windows, and I had to get my HDD replaced.

This time, I want to install Ubuntu and not install the grub loader, instead just booting Ubuntu manually from the boot options during startup. My question is, if I choose to uninstall Ubuntu by deleting partitions again, will I get the same problems with my new scheme i.e. without meddling with the Windows boot process?

Answer (score 1):

First, the default GRUB 2 configuration for Ubuntu sends GRUB 2 to the Ubuntu partition for some critical configuration and support files. This makes GRUB 2 reliant on files on both the EFI System Partition (ESP) and the Ubuntu root (`/`) or `/boot` partition. Thus, deleting the Ubuntu partition almost certainly did *not* damage the EFI System Partition (ESP). Instead, you deprived GRUB 2 of its configuration and support files, leading to an inability to boot *through GRUB 2*. This problem is actually easily overcome by using the computer's built-in boot manager -- typically accessed by pressing Esc, Enter, or a function key when you power on the system. (Unfortunately, there's *no* standardization in user interfaces, so I can't be more specific.) If you'd known this, you could probably have saved yourself a lot of hassle.

Second, installing Ubuntu without a boot loader is pretty pointless, since a boot loader is *required* to boot an OS. That said, the boot loader need not be GRUB 2. [This question and answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313627/uefi-bootloader-alternative-to-grub) briefly describe several alternatives. [My Web page on the subject](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) goes into a lot more detail. If you want to use something other than GRUB 2, you can boot the installer using the "try before installing" option, launch a Terminal, and type:

```
ubiquity -b
```

This command launches the installer and tells it to *not* install GRUB. When the installation finishes, you'll have to install the boot loader of your choice in some way. Options include:

- Install it from Windows
- Install it from the Ubuntu live disk
- Use an emergency boot manager like rEFInd on USB drive to boot Ubuntu, then install from there

If you want a boot process that's safe from problems caused by deleting Ubuntu, you'll need to either use something other than GRUB 2 or create a heavily-customized GRUB 2 configuration, as described [here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting) (Note that, although that page includes a comment that it's outdated, the newer page does *not* describe how to create a custom GRUB setup.)