# BURG doesn't identify Windows 10 but GRUB2 finds windows 10

Tags: grub2, windows, uefi, burg

Well, I really hated GRUB2 's UI. So I thought of moving to BURG. I'm using Windows 10 with Ubuntu 15.10 and Kali-Linux Triple-boot. i installed BURG though https://insanelyi.com/topic/22925-grub-installing-burg-on-ubuntu-1510-configuration-tools/ . i installed it successfully, and BURG finds ubuntu 15.10 and kali linux, but it doesn't find windows 10.

Windows 10 was pre-installed before installing ubuntu and windows 10 is in UEFI settings....

the thing is that GRUB2 finds all the three os and i am able to boot into it but when it comes to BURG , it only finds kali linux and ubuntu.....

is there anyway to fix this???

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, BURG is abandonware. It's also, AFAIK, a BIOS-only boot loader. If your computer came with Windows 10 pre-installed, Windows is almost certainly booting in EFI mode, and so BURG, as a BIOS-only boot loader, won't be able to boot it.

GRUB 2, by contrast, is being actively developed and is available for both BIOS and EFI systems. It can therefore handle the dual-boot task.

The good news is that there are many alternatives to GRUB 2, as described briefly in [this question and answers,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313627/uefi-bootloader-alternative-to-grub) and in more detail in [my Web page on the subject.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) If you wanted to use BURG because of its graphical menus, the best alternative may be my own [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/)