# How can I install Ubuntu alongside Windows on a different hard drive that contains other partitions?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I have Windows installed on my SSD (`sdb`), but its recovery and EFI partitions were created by default on my HDD (`sda`). I have another partition on the HDD for storing some files.

This is the information I got from Ubiquity with a general description of each partition (taken from the Windows partitioning tool):

- `sda1`: Windows recovery partition
- `sda2`: Windows EFI partition
- `sda3`: NTFS general use partition
- `sdb` is occupied by one NTFS Windows partition.

When I tried to install Ubuntu as usual, it didn't recognize Windows. I read how to set up Ubuntu's partitions manually, but it said I couldn't do it while keeping the other `sda` partitions.

Is there a way to do it without losing them?

EDIT: Output of `fdisk -lu`:

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.6 GiB, 1742868480 bytes, 3404040 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 82 MiB, 86011904 bytes, 167992 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 140 MiB, 146841600 bytes, 286800 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 1.6 MiB, 1691648 bytes, 3304 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 12.2 MiB, 12804096 bytes, 25008 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 21 MiB, 22003712 bytes, 42976 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 3.3 MiB, 3411968 bytes, 6664 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 9033DBB1-06EA-4D3F-80DE-DD7C2CBFA9B2

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048    1023999    1021952  499M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2  1024000    1228799     204800  100M EFI System
/dev/sda3  1259520 1783838719 1782579200  850G Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/sdb: 111.8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 1E74C216-5FA5-4648-BDC5-0EC101622203

Device     Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 234438655 234436608 111.8G Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/sdc: 14.6 GiB, 15664676864 bytes, 30595072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x01bf4af5

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1  *     2048 30595071 30593024 14.6G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dual-booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 on different drives with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789519/dual-booting-windows-10-and-ubuntu-16-04-on-different-drives-with-uefi)

Comment: If you can't install Ubuntu, then where where you getting details of these sda partitions from? Windows can't see sda partitions. Or are you getting this data from a live USB stick? Even then if Ubuntu isn't installed it wouldn't give you this.

Comment: @PaulBenson I got it from the Ubuntu USB. It's not copied and pasted, it's a general description of my partitions.

Comment: Make sure you have good backups. Boot files may not be where you think they are. Post this  above so we have more details: `sudo fdisk -lu` Did you turn off Windows fast start up? http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: @oldfred I never actually installed Ubuntu, the information is from the USB stick. I expect this command won't work if I boot from a live installation, right?

Comment: Live installer in live mode is a fully working Ubuntu system. Just a bit slower since on USB flash drive and not updateable. Commands from live installer are often used to repair install on internal drives. Command should work.

Comment: @oldfred posted the output of  'fdisk -lu' above.

Comment: You need to make sure Windows fast start up is off. Use Windows own partitioning tools to shrink the NTFS partition to make unallocated space for Ubuntu. Do not create partitions with Windows. And reboot immediately after changing NTFS partition and run chkdsk. Then installer should see NTFS partitions and let you install into unallocated space. Be sure to boot installer in UEFI mode. See the links posted above in first and fourth comments.