# Fail to upgrade the Ubuntu 12.04 kernel to 3.5

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, kernel

I followed the command in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257617/how-can-i-upgrade-the-ubuntu-12-04-2-kernel-to-3-5-0-23) to upgrade my Ubuntu kernel to 3.5

I entered the command and reboot after installation:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-quantal
```

And after rebooting, I found the kernel is still 3.2.0.

[image]

After that, I tried `apt-cache search linux-image-3.5.0` and `sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.5.0-37-generic`. The messages showed that no new installation needed.

For your information, this is my laptop spesification:

- ASUS A53S with Intel® Core™ i7 CPU 2670QM @ 2.2GHz
- 8GB memory
- nVidia GeForce GT630M

I am not sure if I can upgrade from installing the debs, and suggestions?

---

EDIT:

I tried `sudo update-grub`, and I still cannot see Ubuntu 3.5.0-37 in my grub menu.I also checked grub advanced options for Ubuntu, 3.2.0-49 & 3.5.0-36 & 3.5.0-37 do not exist.

```
rosfuerte@rosfuerte-K53SM:~$ sudo update-grub
[sudo] password for rosfuerte: 
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-37-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-37-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-36-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-49-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-49-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-41-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-41-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-35-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-35-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-32-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-31-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-31-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-30-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-30-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-29-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-29-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
Found Ubuntu 13.04 (13.04) on /dev/sda5
done
rosfuerte@rosfuerte-K53SM:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

try updating grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

---

edit:
did you try reinstalling?

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-generic-lts-quantal
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

---

i googled and found that two os may cause this problem so if ubuntu 12.04 is not your default OS, change your default OS to ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: After updating grub, I still can't see Ubuntu 3.5.0-37 in my grub menu. I've updated my question.