# Problem upgrading from 3.2.0-51-generic to 3.5.0-37-generic

Tags: upgrade, kernel

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and tried to upgrade the kernel from 3.2 to 3.5:
Following a suggestion found here, I ran

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-quantal
```

I had a little trouble with it, but after reboot I have

```
uname -r 

3.5.0-37-generic
```

However, attempting to install the new X stack results in an error:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-lts-quantal

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

 gvfs-daemons : Depends: x11-utils

E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Any suggestions?  I tried "sudo apt-get install gvfs-daemons" and "sudo apt-get install x11-utils", but both were up to date.

Comment: Can you post the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold`?

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/257617/how-can-i-upgrade-the-ubuntu-12-04-2-kernel-to-3-5-0-23

Comment: Braiam: I ran dpkg as you indicated, but it returned nothing.

Comment: ubfan1: That link is where I found the instructions to do what I tried to do. It worked well on another computer, but not on this one (yet).

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, the below is the list of "quantal" packages (mostly X and kernel) on my 12.04.2 system (fresh install), kernel 3.5.0-37.  Probably most of the X packages are not needed...

> $ dpkg -l |fgrep quantal |sort ii  libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-quantal
>   9.0.3-0ubuntu0.4~precise1                        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules ii  libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-quantal:i386 
>   9.0.3-0ubuntu0.4~precise1                        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules ii  libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-quantal
>   9.0.3-0ubuntu0.4~precise1                        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX runtime ii  libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-quantal:i386 
>   9.0.3-0ubuntu0.4~precise1                        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX runtime ii  libglapi-mesa-lts-quantal
>   9.0.3-0ubuntu0.4~precise1                        free implementation of the GL API -- shared library ii  libglapi-mesa-lts-quantal:i386
>   9.0.3-0ubuntu0.4~precise1                        free implementation of the GL API -- shared library ii  libxatracker1-lts-quantal
>   9.0.3-0ubuntu0.4~precise1                        X acceleration library -- runtime ii  linux-generic-lts-quantal
>   3.5.0.37.43                                      Generic Linux kernel image and headers ii  linux-headers-generic-lts-quantal
>   3.5.0.37.43                                      Generic Linux kernel headers ii  linux-image-generic-lts-quantal              3.5.0.37.43
>   Generic Linux kernel image ii  x11-xserver-utils-lts-quantal
>   7.7~3ubuntu1~precise1                            X server utilities ii  xserver-common-lts-quantal
>   2:1.13.0-0ubuntu6.1~precise3                     common files used by
>   various X servers ii  xserver-xorg-core-lts-quantal
>   2:1.13.0-0ubuntu6.1~precise3                     Xorg X server - core
>   server ii  xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-quantal
>   1:7.7+1ubuntu4~precise1                          X.Org X server --
>   input driver metapackage ii  xserver-xorg-input-evdev-lts-quantal
>   1:2.7.3-0ubuntu2~precise1                        X.Org X server --
>   evdev input driver ii  xserver-xorg-input-mouse-lts-quantal
>   1:1.7.2-2build1~precise1                         X.Org X server --
>   mouse input driver ii  xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-quantal
>   1.6.2-1ubuntu5~precise1                          Synaptics TouchPad driver for X.Org server ii  xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse-lts-quantal
>   1:12.9.0-0ubuntu3~precise1                       X.Org X server --
>   VMMouse input driver to use with VMWare ii 
>   xserver-xorg-input-wacom-lts-quantal
>   1:0.17.0-0ubuntu2~precise1                       X.Org X server --
>   Wacom input driver ii  xserver-xorg-lts-quantal
>   1:7.7+1ubuntu4~precise1                          X.Org X server ii 
>   xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-quantal           1:7.7+1ubuntu4~precise1
>   X.Org X server -- output driver metapackage ii 
>   xserver-xorg-video-ati-lts-quantal
>   1:6.99.99~git20120913.8637f772-0ubuntu1~precise2 X.Org X server --
>   AMD/ATI display driver wrapper ii 
>   xserver-xorg-video-cirrus-lts-quantal        1:1.5.1-0ubuntu2~precise1
>   X.Org X server -- Cirrus display driver ii 
>   xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-lts-quantal         1:0.4.3-0ubuntu1~precise1
>   X.Org X server -- fbdev display driver ii 
>   xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-quantal
>   2:2.20.9-0ubuntu2.2~precise1                     X.Org X server --
>   Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver ii 
>   xserver-xorg-video-mach64-lts-quantal        6.9.3-0ubuntu1~precise2
>   X.Org X server -- ATI Mach64 display driver ii 
>   xserver-xorg-video-mga-lts-quantal           1:1.6.2-0ubuntu1~precise2
>   X.Org X server -- MGA display driver ii 
>   xserver-xorg-video-modesetting-lts-quantal   0.5.0-0ubuntu1~precise2
>   X.Org X server -- Generic modesetting driver ii 
>   xserver-xorg-video-neomagic-lts-quantal      1:1.2.7-0ubuntu1~precise1
>   X.Org X server -- Neomagic display driver ii 
>   xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-lts-quantal       1:1.0.2-0ubuntu3~precise2
>   X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver ii 
>   xserver-xorg-video-openchrome-lts-quantal    1:0.3.1-0ubuntu1~precise3
>   X.Org X server -- VIA display driver ii 
>   xserver-xorg-video-r128-lts-quantal          6.9.1-0ubuntu1~precise2
>   X.Org X server -- ATI r128 display driver ii 
>   xserver-xorg-video-radeon-lts-quantal
>   1:6.99.99~git20120913.8637f772-0ubuntu1~precise2 X.Org X server --
>   AMD/ATI Radeon display driver ii  xserver-xorg-video-s3-lts-quantal
>   1:0.6.5-0ubuntu1~precise1                        X.Org X server --
>   legacy S3 display driver ii  xserver-xorg-video-savage-lts-quantal
>   1:2.3.6-0ubuntu1~precise1                        X.Org X server --
>   Savage display driver ii  xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion-lts-quantal
>   1:1.7.7-0ubuntu1~precise1                        X.Org X server --
>   SiliconMotion display driver ii  xserver-xorg-video-sis-lts-quantal
>   1:0.10.7-0ubuntu1~precise2                       X.Org X server -- SiS
>   display driver ii  xserver-xorg-video-sisusb-lts-quantal
>   1:0.9.6-0ubuntu1~precise1                        X.Org X server -- SiS
>   USB display driver ii  xserver-xorg-video-tdfx-lts-quantal
>   1:1.4.5-0ubuntu1~precise2                        X.Org X server --
>   tdfx display driver ii  xserver-xorg-video-trident-lts-quantal
>   1:1.3.6-0ubuntu2~precise1                        X.Org X server --
>   Trident display driver ii  xserver-xorg-video-vesa-lts-quantal
>   1:2.3.2-0ubuntu1~precise1                        X.Org X server --
>   VESA display driver ii  xserver-xorg-video-vmware-lts-quantal
>   1:12.0.2+git.e5ac80d8-0ubuntu1~precise2          X.Org X server --
>   VMware display driver

Comment: ubfan1: It appears that the only "quantal" package on my system is the kernel:  $ dpkg -l |fgrep quantal
ii  linux-image-generic-lts-quantal

Comment: ubfan1: I noticed that you had "x11-xserver-utils-lts-quantal" so I started to install it. However, the install wanted to remove the ubuntu desktop, so I did not proceed further. Are you running the desktop?  I was going to post the output here, but I ran out of "characters".

Comment: The system seems to be running fine as it is, so I'll just use it this way. Hopefully I don't really need the new X stack??

Comment: I'm running the standard Unity desktop.  If you're running OK, then leave it.  I was surprised to see all the X packages, I thought there would be 3 kernel related quantal packages.