# New Linux kernel in Ubuntu?

Tags: kernel

I've been reading about the new 3.12 kernel and I am excited about the increased performance reported by Phoronix.

How long will it be before Ubuntu releases include the 3.12 kernel?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu is about stability over newest versions.That includes the kernel.

13.10 is using 3.11. I doubt it will be included into 13.10. I would expect it to have been included during release if we would get it.

So I believe you will probably see kernel 3.12 in Ubuntu 14.04.

But no-one it stopping you from including it. Some older topics, but the method is still valid (just need to update the file names):

- [How to update kernel to the latest mainline version without any Distro-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade)
- [How can I upgrade the Ubuntu LTS kernel to newer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257617/how-can-i-upgrade-the-ubuntu-12-04-2-kernel-to-3-5-0-23)

Topics related to installing 3.12:

- http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-kernel-3-12-rc2-on-ubuntu-linux-mint-elementary-os-debian-and-pear-os/
- http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-the-linux-kernel-3-12-rc1-on-ubuntu-linux-mint-elementary-os-and-debian/

Just a warning: this is not for the fainthearted. And messing up might mean a re-install. And as always: make a back-up. Or even two.