# What does x86 mean for installing a new hardware enablement (HWE) stack in 64 bit Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, kernel, 64-bit, hardware, hardware-enablement-stack

I'd like to install 13.10 (Saucy) **hardware enablement (HWE) stack** to my Ubuntu 12.04 (64-bit) because I need a newer Linux kernel.

[This wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) explains what "hardware enablement stacks" are. Among other things it says:

> Only the -generic **x86** kernel flavor ... will be supported...

Also, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/257623/232323) says:

> ...This is only recommended for x86 hardware installations...

Is x86 here synonymous to 32-bit/i386 architecture (but not 64-bit/AMD64), or is it i386/AMD64 (but not ARM)?

Can I install this "hardware enablement stack" in a 64-bit/AMD64 Ubuntu? Will it be supported with future updates?

Comment: Yes, x86 means amd64 or i386. If you just want a new kernel, you could install one from the mainline kernel PPA. You could also upgrade to 14.04.

Comment: @bain Thanks! It's good news. Do I understand it correctly, that if I install it from the mainline kernel PPA, I will not have automatic updates? And I will have a better chance of some incompatibility issues than with a well tested Ubuntu's "hardware enablement stack"?

Comment: That is probably true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, x86 means amd64 or i386. The reference `only the -generic kernel flavor` refers to the various [kernel packages available](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/linux-image); "generic" is the regular kernel, but there are also kernels optimised for virtual machines and low latency, and those other kernels are not supported by the hardware enablement stack.