# Latest Kernel for ubuntu 14.04.4

Tags: kernel

I am currently running Ubuntu 14.04.4 with kernel version 3.16. There are posts that indicate that the current kernel version is 3.19. Should I upgrade, if yes then how? Wouldn't the kernel be automatically upgraded by  Ubuntu Software Center?

The output of `hostnamectl status`  is given below.

```
Static hostname: neelanshu-HP-Notebook
         Icon name: computer-laptop
           Chassis: laptop
           Boot ID: fc22e28db4834eb3862e269203e58923
  Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 3.16.0-69-generic
      Architecture: x86_64
```

Please advise. 
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I upgrade the Ubuntu LTS kernel to newer?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/257617/how-can-i-upgrade-the-ubuntu-lts-kernel-to-newer)

Comment: The latest is 4.2, actually: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/linux-generic-lts-wily

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You do not have to upgrade your kernel. Kernel 3.16 still gets security and bug fixing updates.

But you CAN upgrade the kernel to 3.19 by

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

or to 4.2 by

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

It is even possible to upgrade to kernel 4.4, but that may cause issues with DKMS modules

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

Comment: Is there any disadvantage, in terms of performance, security etc, if I stay with 3.16?

Comment: I do not think so. New kernels are needed to support new hardware. And there is no need to upgrade if there is no specific reason.

Comment: You need newer kernel for "cutting-edge technologies" like zfs or docker.

Comment: Note that kernels can have security vulnerabilities like any other package. Eg.: https://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3106-2/